# Requests Library in flutter is not storing the cookies, when application exits

Tags: flutter, cookies, sharedpreferences

Earlier my app was using the flutter requests library 3.3.0, when i recently update the library to 4.4.1 . The cookie was not getting stored when the app exits. Is there a way to solve this without changing the package

Answer (score 0):

I have got the solution to fix this issue.

Call a secure api, and automatically the cookies will get stored in the Request library. Fetch those cookies using the ***Requests.getStoredCookies(hostname)*** and convert the Cookie to string and store it in the shared preferences. And when the app exits and when the user comes back read the shared preferences and parse the string to cookiejar using the ***CookieJar.parseCookiesString(storedCooks!)*** and set the stored cookies using the ***Requests.setStoredCookies(hostname, parsedCookies)*** and now the problem is solved

**SETTING THE COOKIES**

```
String? url = env?.getBaseUrl();
String hostname = Requests.getHostname(url);
var r12 = await Requests.post(url,
    headers: <String, String>{'authorization': authEncryptionKey!},
    json: {"shouldGenerateCookie": true, "ipSession": false},
    timeoutSeconds: 60, persistCookies: true);
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

var requestcookies = await Requests.getStoredCookies(hostname).then((value) =>
{
  cookiesInString = value.values.first.toString()
});
sharedPreferences.setString('cookies', cookiesInString!);
```

**The Cookies are set in the shared preferences, Reading the cookies**

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
String? storedCooks  = await sharedPreferences.getString("cookies");
String hostname = Requests.getHostname(url);
var parsedCookies = CookieJar.parseCookiesString(storedCooks!);
await Requests.setStoredCookies(hostname, parsedCookies);
var cookies = await Requests.getStoredCookies(hostname);
```

The cookies are been set to request library in the form of CookieJar